# Skype silently eat hdd space during call

Tags: windows-7, skype

Why my skype eat my hdd space during call ? In about 1-1,5hour of call it eat all free space on system drive (60GB!!!!).

I locate two files in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Skype for desktop:

- first in media-stack, file Skype.msrtc-0-3212298353.blog, this file looks as small about 5,4MB but in real have alocated 23,2GB (more or less, depend on call length)
- second file located in skylib, file slimcore-0-2793155111.blog, again this file look as about 6MB but have alocated 20GB (again it vary depend on call length)

This problem was on skype 7, same problem I have on Skype 8, I tested this on another PC but under my account and this problem still persist on another PC, it eat my hdd space, only way how to get back this space is turn off and turn on Skype after call.

Have anyone idea what is this and how to fix it ? (reinstall doesnt work and it happen on two PCs).

[image: Picture of Skype space allocation on disk]

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this mystery, reason was (and installed on both PC's) Raxco PerfectDisk, seems StealthPatrol or some service from PerfectDisk somehow interference with Skype.
Odd but solved.